# can i change the window.top.location from within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

```
<html>
<title>iframe_test</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="test_page_with_links.html" width="whatever" height="whatever" /></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to make an iframe people can add to their own websites that adds additional navigation links, but if I try to change the window.top.location from within the iframe to let's say /profile, the browser goes to my website that's housing the iframe /profile instead of the website the iframe is on /profile — hope this makes sense

Comment: What you want to change? the content inside the iframe or the content of the window that contains the iframe?

Comment: Iframes are untouchable. You can't change anything what has to do with an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add target="_top" to your links

```
<a href="profile.htm" target="_top"></a>
```

Comment: the links are within an iframe, and i want to put that iframe on a web page and have the links take my somewhere on the domain of the website the iframe is on, not the domain the iframe is on

Comment: i tried adding target="_top" to the links within the iframe but they still go to the url of the iframe rather than the url of the website with the iframe on it

Answer (score 0):

give your iframe a name and the link a target that matches the name.

```
<iframe src="whatever.html" name="my_frame">

<a href="http://www.somewhere.com" target="my_frame">
```